# What if I don't want xstream to use an object's readObject/writeObject implementation?

Tags: xstream

I have customized the java serialization (via `readObject` and `writeObject`) of an object to omit properties to minimize the `jgroups` traffic between cluster nodes but I don't want to omit those properties from the `xml` produced/consumed by `xstream`. Is there a way to control the java serialization used by `xstream`, such that I don't omit these properties?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Sorry, I misunderstood your question that you **don't** want to omit fields.

If the data model implements `Serializable` and have a `readObject` and `writeObject` method, these methods will invoked automatically by XStream or more exact by `SerializationMethodInvoker#callReadObject` and `SerializationMethodInvoker#callWriteObject`. I haven't see any configuration flag to avoid these calls.

Furthermore, transient fields omitted automatically. See `AbstractReflectionConverter#shouldUnmarshalField`:

```
    protected boolean shouldUnmarshalField(final Field field) {
        return !(Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers()) && !shouldUnmarshalTransientFields());
}
```

and

```
protected boolean shouldUnmarshalTransientFields() {
    return false;
}
```

So there is no configuration flag to avoid that `shouldUnmarshalTransientFields` returns every time `false`;

There are many ways to omit fields with XSream.

1. Via annotation: `@XStreamOmitField`
2. Via configuring the XStream object: `XStream#omitField(Class definedIn, String fieldName)`
3. Using Java's syntax for it: `transient Type field`

Answer (score 0):

The class in question, Form, does implement `Serializable` and has a `readObject` and a `writeObject`.

I wound up registering a very basic converter class and discovered that writeObject did not get invoked when I invoked `toXML`. Which is seemingly what I was looking for. I can now omit certain properties from the jgroups serialization stream (via `writeObject`) that will not be omitted from the xtream generated xml.

Here's my converter class...

```
package foo.form;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.javabean.JavaBeanConverter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.Mapper;

public class FormConverter extends JavaBeanConverter {

    public FormConverter(Mapper mapper) {
        super(mapper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return Form.class == clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        super.marshal(source, writer, context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        return super.unmarshal(reader, context);
    }
}
```